# Find the resulting Sum after adding to the previous value in a Python list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a random number as input, lets say 5. What I need is the sum of the numbers 5 + 55 + 555 + 5555 + 55555.

Kindly help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: `print(5 + 55 + 555 + 5555 + 55555)` maybe?

Comment: n=input()
n=int(n)
sum=0
input_list=[1,10,100,1000, 10000]
final_list=[]
for i in input_list:

    final_list.append(i*n)

result=sum(final_list)
print(result)

Comment: Including my code here. My issue is I am unable to recursively add the current result to my previous one.

Comment: if the number is 4, what will be the answer? "4+44+444+4444" or "4+44+444+4444+44444"?

Comment: If the number is 4, then the answer returned must be 4+44+444+4444+44444=49380

Comment: @flyingmachine What happened if number is larger than 9, for example, 12?

Comment: The max value of the input number cannot be greater than 9. Sorry I forgot to mention this in my question. Apologies.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: @flyingmachine why not just use`(1+11+111+1111+11111)*i`?

Answer (score 1):

You should track the sum and the number to sum separately like:

```
i = 0
digits = 5
the_sum = 0
for j in range(digits):
    i = i * 10 + digits
    the_sum += i

print(the_sum)
print(5 + 55 + 555 + 5555 + 55555)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is useful.
Please see comments as below:

```
def calc_iter(n, length = 1):
    value = ''
    for l in range(length): value += str(n)  # generate string number by length
    result = int(value)                      # convert string number to int
    if length == n: return result            # return int if length is equal n
    return result + calc_iter(n, length = length+1) # sum

num = int(input())
print (calc_iter(num))
```

```
3
369  // 3 + 33 + 333
5
61725 // 5 + 55 + 555 + 5555 +55555
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
 s=0
 for i in range(1,6):
     x="5"*i
     s+=eval(x)
 print(5 + 55 + 555 + 5555 + 55555)
 print(s)
```

**Output**

```
61725
61725
```